# How to send empty route parameter to a web API?

Tags: c#, api

I am calling a web api using this code

```
public class SearchController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/SearchController/{paramOne}/{paramTwo}")]
    public string Get(string paramOne, string paramTwo)
    {
        return "The [Route] with multiple params worked.\nP1 : " + paramOne + "    P2 : " + paramTwo;
    }
}
```

It works fine.

if I call `https://localhost:44319/api/SearchSelectController/Mike/Tom`

I get this

```
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" id="dark-mode-custom-link"/>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" id="dark-mode-general-link"/>
<style lang="en" type="text/css" id="dark-mode-custom-style"/>
<style lang="en" type="text/css" id="dark-mode-native-style"/>
The [Route] with multiple params worked. P1 : Mike P2 : Tom
</string>
```

but if I am sending empty string for the first or 2nd parameter

```
https://localhost:44319/api/SearchSelectController//Tom
```

I get this error

```
<Error>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" id="dark-mode-custom-link"/>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" id="dark-mode-general-link"/>
<style lang="en" type="text/css" id="dark-mode-custom-style"/>
<style lang="en" type="text/css" id="dark-mode-native-style"/>
<Message>No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://localhost:44319/api/SearchSelectController/Tom'.</Message>
<MessageDetail>No type was found that matches the controller named 'SearchSelectController'.</MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

So I wonder how can I send empty string as parameter for a web API?

Comment: Are you sure these should be route parameters? What do paramOne and paramTwo actually represent?

Comment: (as a side note: `int paramOne` could _never_ be `"Mike"`) i don't think route parameters are the way to go here. maybe use query parameters instead?

Comment: you can use `{paramOne?}` for get null values in routing

Comment: I don't think its possible to send "empty" parameters. If you need paramOne and paramTwo as route parameters and they don't need to come in pairs, you should define different routes for these cases

Comment: @TheTanic this is my first time to use APIs... so what is the right approach?

Comment: @asmgx Take a look at my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to send empty route parameters, because they break the URL-schema. 
To solve your problem you can send them as GET-Parameters. So your method in the Controller looks like:

```
[Route("api/SearchController")]
public string Get(string paramOne = null, string paramTwo= null)
  {
    return "The [Route] with multiple params worked.\nP1 : " + paramOne + "    P2 : " + paramTwo;
  }
```

The URLs look like this:

```
https://localhost:44319/api/SearchSelectController?paramOne=Mike&paramTwo=Tom
https://localhost:44319/api/SearchSelectController?paramTwo=Tom
https://localhost:44319/api/SearchSelectController?paramOne=Mike
```

Answer (score 2):

If each input parameter may be null or any combination of these, tell the action method that each of these may be null.
The following code also supports null values.

```
[Route("api/SearchController/{paramOne?}/{paramTwo?}")]
public string Get(string paramOne = null, string paramTwo = null)
{
    return "The [Route] with multiple params worked.\nP1 : " + paramOne + "    P2 : " + paramTwo;
}
```

**Or another method**

set the `WebApiConfig.cs` file as follows. If you do not have this file, create it in the `App_Start` folder.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
     public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
     {
       config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

       config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "myroute",
            routeTemplate: "api/SearchController/{paramOne}/{paramTwo}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Search", action = "Get", paramOne = RouteParameter.Optional, paramTwo = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

         config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
              name: "DefaultApi",
              routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
              defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional}
        );
    }
}
```

and register above class in global.cs

```
protected void Application_Start()
{   /................
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    /................
}
```

Finally the api method

```
public string Get(string paramOne = null, string paramTwo = null)
{
    return "The [Route] with multiple params worked.\nP1 : " + paramOne + "    P2 : " + paramTwo;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case only one solution exists.
Use query parameter like below:

```
public class SearchController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/SearchController")]
    public string Get([FromQuery] ModelWithTwoParam model)
    {
        return "The [Route] with multiple params worked.\nP1 : " + model.paramOne + "    P2 : " + model.paramTwo;
    }
}
```

see documents:

[[FromQuery]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromqueryattribute?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: how to call the api?

Comment: https://localhost:44319/api/SearchSelectController?paramOne=Mike